# How to use Split to tokenize text file using the new line character as a delimiter

Tags: vba, excel

Using VBA how would one go about using the VBA.Split method to tokenize text file using the new line character as a delimiter?

The following don't seem to work:

```
Split(myText, "\n")

Split(myText, vbCrLf)

Split(myText, vbNewLine)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a little investigation turns out the answer is:

```
Split(data, vbLf)
```

Comment: While using `VBA` is useful to indentify worksheet functions and the vb constants is is redudant in working code. I suggest you follow Issuns's lead

Comment: Answer edited to take into account comments from brettdj & Issuns

Comment: Thanks for the close out, I did upvote your question early today

Answer (score 8):

If you are working within `VBA`, you don't need all the `VBA` tags:

```
Split(data, vbLf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get it work is

```
split(myText,Chr(13) + Chr(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the anser on [chandoo](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/08/23/split-text-on-new-line-macro/):

```
Split(ActiveCell.Value, Chr(10))
```